# (Infinite Dimensional) Convex Programming

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I am very new to linear programming and there is something I can't figure out about linear and convex programming.

Convex programming is a generalization of infinite dimensional linear programming.

It appears there exists efficient methods to solve convex programming (in tractable time). However, these methods appear to fail for infinite dimensional linear programming and I can't understand why? especially as infinite dimensional linear programming is a special case of convex programming.

Is it related to the dual gap issue ? Indeed, convex optimization approach doesn't have a dual gap but infinite dimensional linear programming can have.

Also, is there a difference between convex programming and convex programming over the space of measures ? Or can we consider that convex programming over the space of measures is included inside convex programming ? Therefore methods for convex programming would also be suitable for convex programming over the space of measures

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This seems to be quite vague. At least you should define what you understand under "linear programming" and "convex programming".

Comment: I see a linear programing as having a linear objective function and linear constraints and convex programming as having a convex objective function and convex feasible set.

Comment: What is a "linear constraint" in an infinite-dimensional space $X$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant infinitely many constraints.

Comment: If you are not able to write down a precise definition, it is not possible to answer your question.